# angular controller called only in the first time the state load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

part of myApp.js:

```
.state('app.home', {
  url: "/home",
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
    }
  }
})
.state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl',
    resolve : {
        myCurrentUser : function(myCurrentUserServ) {
            return myCurrentUserServ.promiseToHaveMyCurrentUser();
        }
    },
  })

  .state('app.list', {
    url: "/lists/:listId",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/listDashboard.html",
        controller: 'listDashboardCtrl',
        resolve : {
              currentList : function(currentListServ, $stateParams) {
                  return currentListServ.promiseToHaveList($stateParams.listId);
              }
        },
      }
    }
  })
.state('app.createWordsList', {
          url: "/create-list",
          views: {
            'menuContent': {
              templateUrl: "templates/createWordsList.html",
              controller: 'createWordsListCtrl'
            }
          }
        });
```

'createWordsListCtrl' controller :

```
.controller('createWordsListCtrl', function($scope,myCurrentUserServ , $ionicModal, $timeout,$firebaseAuth,$state,$q) {
    console.log("gg"); 
});
```

when I goes to app.createWordsList at the first time, the createWordsListCtrl is running , but if I change state (for example to 'app.home') and then return back, the createWordsListCtrl not run at all.
it's happen to all states besides those with state params(aor example app.list).

Comment: Should work - something else is going in your app that is not visible from the code you posted: http://plnkr.co/edit/PkTCauGI9qMTXHsFzNd8?p=preview

Comment: thanks!
it's also ptint ---> Start:   app.myPage{} -> app.createWordsList{}
controllers.js:278 <--- Success: app.myPage{} -> app.createWordsList{} for me, but the controller itself not running...

Comment: soory, my bad. I user ionic and it has auto cache... thanks